# Force leading spaces in \if result

Tags: context

```
\def\test#1{
\def\csv{#1}
\ifx\csv\empty
\else
X\fi
}


\starttext

This is a test x\test{1}x.

\stoptext
```

Should result in `xXx`, but shows `x Xx`. How do I avoid the leading space here?

Edit: Ok, this has been resolved, but what if I need one or more leading spaces before the `X`such as `x    Xx`. Using this doesn't help:

```
\def\test#1{%
\def\csv{#1}%
\ifx\csv\empty%
\else%
    X\fi%
}%
```

Comment: Add `%` at the end of the lines.

Comment: Wicked @percusse. Why is a `%` here? Thanks!

Comment: your `\test` macro has two (not "single") space tokens in the first two lines

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines